# R: Matching package, output datasets for matched data

Tags: r

I am using Package Matching (http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/matching/). I manage to match my data but I don'n understand how to get out a dataset for matched and unmatched cases. In manual (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matching/Matching.pdf) page 20 (Value) contains mdata, index.treated  and index.control but I don't know how to utilize them. Could anyone help me, please?

mdata 
A list which contains the matched datasets produced by Match. Three datasets
are included in this list: Y, Tr and X.

index.treated 
A vector containing the observation numbers from the original dataset for the
treated observations in the matched dataset. This index in conjunction with
index.control can be used to recover the matched dataset produced by Match.
For example, the X matrix used by Match can be recovered by rbind(X[index.treated,],X[index.control,]).
The user should generally just examine the output of mdata.

index.control 
A vector containing the observation numbers from the original data for the control
observations in the matched data. This index in conjunction with index.treated
can be used to recover the matched dataset produced by Match. For example, the
X matrix used by Match can be recovered by rbind(X[index.treated,],X[index.control,]).
The user should generally just examine the output of mdata.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post but thought I would share

Given the following example of matching directly on given variables "age" (within 5 years) and "married" within the example data lalonde in the matching package:

(This is a more complex example for the benefit of people like me who found no similar examples)

```
#install.packages("Matching")
library(Matching)
data(lalonde)
    X  <- cbind(lalonde$age,lalonde$married)
    colnames(X)<-c("age","married")
    Tr  <- lalonde$treat
#Define caliper for age within 5 years (see package documentation for caliper)
    5/sd(lalonde$age) #=0.7041973
# 5-to-one matching with replacement (the "M=5" option), with ties set to false to limit multiple matches
# Exact matching on "married" (the "exact=c(0,1)" option), corresponding to 0 (false) for age, 1 (true) for "married"
    rr  <- Match(Tr=Tr, X=X, M=2,ties=F,exact=c(0,1),caliper=0.7041973) #caliper set to match age within 5 years
    summary(rr)
#Put results (rownames of treated and controls) into a dataframe
    rr<-data.frame(rr$index.treated,rr$index.control)
    colnames(rr)<-c("cases","controls")
    lalonde$rowID<-as.numeric(rownames(lalonde))
```

To join the original characteristics of your cases and controls to the results of the matching you can (1) do a simple match or (2) use the sqldf package, there are bound to be more options

```
#Option 1 to join case control table to original characteristics
    rr$CaseMarried <- lalonde$married[match(rr$cases, lalonde$rowID)]
    rr$ControlMarried<-lalonde$married[match(rr$controls, lalonde$rowID)]
    rr$CaseAge <- lalonde$age[match(rr$cases, lalonde$rowID)]
    rr$ControlAge<-lalonde$age[match(rr$controls, lalonde$rowID)]
    rr

#Option 2 to join case control table to original characterisitcs using sqldf    
#install.packages("sqldf")
    library(sqldf)
    sqldf1<-sqldf(
      "SELECT a.cases, b.age AS CaseAge, b.married AS CaseMarried, 
      a.controls, c.age AS ControlAge, c.married AS ControlMarried
      FROM a
      INNER JOIN lalonde b
      ON a.cases=b.rowID
      INNER JOIN lalonde c
      ON a.controls=c.rowID")
```

Comment: Excellent answer. There is a real lack of clear documentation out there on how to do a simple case-control match in R.

Answer (score 0):

Following the example from the manual, if you have:

```
gen1<-GenMatch(Tr=Tr,X=X,BalanceMatrix=BalanceMatrix,pop.size=1000)

mgen1<-Match(Y=Y,Tr=Tr,Weight.matrix=gen1)
```

then you can get the data by typing:

```
mgen1$mdata
```

you can save it as a data.frame

```
mgen1.data<-data.frame(mgen1$mdata)
```